# Error: Cannot find module 'once'

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack, meanjs, npm-install

```
Error: Cannot find module 'once'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/got/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

I'm getting this error when I try running my `server.js` with nodemon. I looked in my `node_modules` folder and there is a 'once' folder in there. I tried

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

to remove the entire `node_modules` folder and reinstall but it didn't work. I also did

```
npm install --save once
```

and still didn't work.

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "FullMean_Friends",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "mongoose": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the module once used  by your application or nodemon?

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something wrong in your require because it should work.  This works for me `npm install once && node -e "require('once')" `  Also you are missing in your dependencies which is incorrect if you need it in your application.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/got/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules/end-of-stream/node_modules/once` exist and have both `package.json` and `once.js`? (yes, that's all a single path and it should exist as per `end-of-stream`'s `package.json`)

In any case the problem is in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/` and not wherever your application is. You could try `sudo npn install once` in that directory as last resort.

Comment: tried npm install once && node -e "require('once')"  and sudo npm install once, no luck. I also added "once": "latest" in package.json in the dependencies, still no luck.

Comment: I suspect it's something that has to do with my npm. None of my applications is running and it's showing Error: Cannot find module 'once'.

Comment: Got it working with going to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/l‌​atest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/got/node_modules/duplexify/n‌​ode_modules/end-of-stream    and do a npm install. Something was missing, but works now.